# Is there a bug with greetings (word "Hi") in the edit answer functionality?

Tags: support

I have edited an answer which starts with "Hi, guys", [image]

But every time I hit save, I have a truncated edit with no "Hi,"[image]

Is that a bug or it is a feature?

Comment: A better question would be: if you're editing a post that starts *"Hi guys"*, why are you not removing that as part of your edit?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The "Hi" is automatically removed from the start of the post.
Greetings like that are considered "noise" on Stack Overflow and shouldn't be used in posts.

Comment: Hi, there! Well, thank for the info, didnt know! I wouldnt even thought of that because it seems like the polite way of conversation.

Comment: [We now automatically remove salutations from posts as they are entered. I got really tired of performing this edit over and over, so anything matching the form of …](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989) [Help-Center: Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Comment: @Zanshin13: Yes, it's the polite way *for conversation*. Whatever gave you the idea that SO is or should be for conversation instead of for questions and answers?

Comment: @Deduplicator Thanks for the enlightenment. Really appreciate. Goodbye and have a nice day!

Comment: @Zanshin13 are you doing that on purpose?

Comment: Hello @jonrsharpe, how you doing? Nice dog you have there! I think there is a slight possibility of some sort of joking in my words, so don't be so angry I meant no offence, just hoped that my humble sense of humor(or its absence) will make someone smile. Also don't forget to do gymnastics for your eyes!

(well, I am totally gonna stop myself now. I hope.)

Comment: @Zanshin13 Stack Overflow is not a forum, we're not having conversations. Think of it as a reference document, such as Wikipedia or Encyclopedia Britannica. Do you see those start off with "hi dear reader, let's discuss [Hurricane Gert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurricane_Gert_(1993)), it was this really bad hurricane"? Nope.

Comment: http://img.memecdn.com/i-had-fun-once_o_793160.jpg